# Next.js error: Text content did not match

Tags: next.js, localization, i18next, react-i18next

I am using react-i18next in my next.js project for localization. But I take these errors when I refresh the page.

**Errors**

1. Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "page_about" Client: "About Us"
2. Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>.
3. Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
4. Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

**src/configs/i18n.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'

i18n
  // Enables the i18next backend
  .use(Backend)

  // Enable automatic language detection
  .use(LanguageDetector)

  // Enables the hook initialization module
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'tr',
    backend: {
      /* translation file path */
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}.json'
    },
    fallbackLng: 'tr',
    debug: false,
    keySeparator: false,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ','
    }
  })

export default i18n
```

**_app.js**

```
...
import 'src/configs/i18n'

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

    const getLayout = Component.layout ?? (page => <Layout>{page}</Layout>)

    return (
        <>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    {
                        getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
                    }
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Provider>
        </>
    )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const ctx = await App.getInitialProps(context)

    return {
        ...ctx,
    };
};


export default MyApp
```

**Translations.js**

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Translations = ({ text }) => {
  // ** Hook
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  return <>
    {`${t(text)}`}
  </>
}

export default Translations
```

**I use in a component**

```
...
<Translations text={subItem.name} />
...
```

I tried to use next-i18next, Suspense, namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass serverSideTranslation function to your page component in order for it to access the transalation file like this :

```
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
props: {
 ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
  "common", 
 ])),
},
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work either. There are same errors.

_...
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
    props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
            "common",
        ])),
    },
});

export default MyApp_

Comment: You have to do this on page level not in app component

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I used "appWithTranslation" in _app.js and "serverSideTranslations" in per page.